# Data Validation for creating folders

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

The company sends invoices to clients. I created a macro that will put the client's invoice into their folder, stored under the year that that invoice was created.

Given it's January of 2020, invoices will be stored under the 2020 folder, and then by client name.

Once 2020 is over and a 2021 folder has yet to be created, will my current code handle this appropriately?

The code determines if a client folder already exists, and if it doesn't creates a folder under the current year with that client's name as the folder.

I'm assuming there will be some type of error for the following years because those folders are yet to be created.
My hope is that, instead of an error, it will go to the `ErrorHandlerCreateNewYearFolder`, to create the folder path, that year's new folder, and the client's new folder.

```vb
If fdObj.FolderExists("C:\Users\" & strInvoiceYear & "\ " & GroupID) Then 'if the Clients folder already exists....
    Call EmailClient((EmailValue), (GroupID)) '...then the necessary data required is already availiable, so it calls to the EmailClient sub function
Else
        
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandlerCreateNewYearFolder ' In the occation of a potential error, the code below will skip the run time error and try its best to handle this
    fdObj.CreateFolder ("C:\Users\" & strInvoiceYear & "\ " & GroupID)
    Exit Sub
    ' INSIGHT: THE LINE OF CODE BELOW CREATES A FOLDER THAT CONTAINS THE GROUPID OF A CLIENT WITHIN THAT YEAR. SO GIVEN THAT THE CURRENT YEAR IS 2020, IT WILL STORE ALL INVOICES WITHIN THAT FOLDER
    ' HOWEVER, THERE IS NO CURRENT 2021,2020, ETC FOLDERS, SO THIS LINE OF CODE WILL BE UNABLE TO DETERMINE THE CORRECT PATH OF strInvoiceYear BECAUSE THIS VARIABLE'S (THAT CURRENT YEAR) FOLDER HAS
    ' YET TO HAVE BEEN CREATED. SO THERE MAY BE A RUN TIME ERROR. HOWEVER, THIS CODE BELOW SHOULD HELP OVERCOME THIS POTENTIAL ISSUE
        
ErrorHandlerCreateNewYearFolder: 'THIS IS AN ERROR HANDLER, SO IF THE NEW YEAR STARTS, LIKE 2021, AND NO 2021 FOLDER HAS BEEN CREATED, THE PROGRAM WILL GO HERE
    fdObj.CreateFolder ("C:\Users\" & strInvoiceYear)  ' IN WHICH THE PROGRAM WILL THEN CREATE THE NEW YEAR FOLDER
    fdObj.CreateFolder ("C:\Users\" & strInvoiceYear & "\ " & GroupID) ' AND THEN CREATE THE NEW CLIENT FOLDER OF THAT YEAR
    Resume Next
        
    MsgBox ("Folder created successfully."), vbInformation ' notifies user that a new folder has been created for the client
    Call EmailClient((EmailValue), (GroupID)) ' This then calls to the EmailClient sub function where the data from that client will then be emailed to them
End If
```

Comment: You procedure has too many responsibilities. Move code into smaller procedure scopes (pass parameters as needed), such that you limit the reasons for it to fail. Something responsible for creating new year's folders shouldn't be also responsible for sending emails, or popping any message box.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for an error handler here. This is pretty straightforward.

I pulled the `Call` out. We're calling `EmailClient` no matter what, so you don't have to nest it in your conditional. Instead, run your checks, make the folder if necessary, then call `EmailClient` with what you've got.

Your first conditional checks if the folder exists. If it does, great, no more need for a conditional. If it doesn't, does its parent? If the answer is no, make it. If the answer is yes, make the child. Then send.

```vb
If fdObj.FolderExists("C:\Users\" & strInvoiceYear & "\ " & GroupID) = True Then

'Check if the parent folder exists (returns true if it doesn't)
ElseIf fdObj.FolderExists("C:\Users\" & strInvoiceYear) = False Then
    'Create parent
    fdObj.CreateFolder ("C:\Users\" & strInvoiceYear)
    'Create group folder
    fdObj.CreateFolder ("C:\Users\" & strInvoiceYear & "\ " & GroupID)
Else
    fdObj.CreateFolder ("C:\Users\" & strInvoiceYear & "\ " & GroupID)
End If

Call EmailClient((EmailValue), (GroupID))

End Sub
```

If you really want to add an error handler, I'd put it before the call to `EmailClient` or inside of `EmailClient`. What you're doing here should be extremely straightforward with correct conditional formatting.

Also, just as a note, your comments are like way too long. If it's a short comment, go ahead and stick it after the code. If it's a long comment, put it before, and break up the even longer ones to multiple lines. No one likes scrolling sideways.

Ideally you would use an `If Not` to skip the first clause altogether, but I wanted to keep it readable for you, given the amount the code you provided was commented out.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Sorry about the comments, I'm still fairly new to this and appreciate any advice that can help others who are helping me. For whatever reason I never really thought about using the decision structure to resolve this. Given that I'm constantly testing this and will get occasional run time errors, I figured that this was the best course of action. Thanks again.

Comment: Doing I/O work is more than enough justification for having error-handling in a procedure: the code doesn't know that the current user has the permissions to create that folder at that location. Maybe the user does, maybe it doesn't. I maintain that emailing the client should be a completely separate thing. Also, holy parentheses, Batman! `Call EmailClient((EmailValue), (GroupID))` should be just `EmailClient EmailValue, GroupID`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon the parentheses are obviously the result of me copying and pasting his code. Feel free to edit my post if you see fit. Also, my comment about the error handler was directly in response to how it was originally written, which was essentially as a branched conditional. I look forward to your answer to see how it should properly be written.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I've tried to keep the parentheses down, but for whatever reason I get a compiler error expecting a end of statement. So I figured that this was the best alternative. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GraysonG If you omit `Call` you can omit the parentheses

Comment: @GraysonG what "no need for an error handler here" stands for, is about using error handling for flow control - this answer neatly demonstrates how to use proper control flow statements (`If...Else...End If`) to get rid of the spaghettified conditional goto-jumps. My comment was just to clarify that any I/O work always warrants proper error handling, since such code can fail for reasons beyond the control of your code.